# How to call a method from a different method within the same class in an if statement

Tags: if-statement, methods, call

I'm trying to call the direction from the step() method in an if statement in the boolean method but it keeps saying it cannot find the variable direction.  Can anybody help me figure out how to correctly do this?

```
public class SelfAvoidingRandomWalk
{
    private char[][] board ;
    private char symbol ;
    private int lengthOfWalk, currRow, currColumn ;

    public SelfAvoidingRandomWalk(int numRows, int numColumns, 
                                 int startRow, int startColumn)
    {
        board = new char[numRows][numColumns] ;
        lengthOfWalk = 0 ;
        symbol = '$' ;
        board[startRow][startColumn] = symbol ;
        currRow = startRow ;
        currColumn = startColumn ; 
    }

    private final static int NORTH = 8 ;
    private final static int SOUTH = 2 ;
    private final static int WEST = 4 ;
    private final static int EAST = 6 ;

    public void step(int direction)
    { 
        if (direction == NORTH)
        {
            if (currRow == 0)
            {
                currRow = board.length ;
            }
            currRow-- ;
            symbol = 'N' ;
        }
        else if (direction == SOUTH)
        {
            currRow = (currRow + 1) % board.length ;
            symbol = 'S' ;
        }
        else if (direction == EAST)
        {
            currColumn = (currColumn + 1) % board[0].length ;
            symbol = 'E' ;
        }
        else if (direction == WEST)
        {
            if (currColumn == 0)
            {
                currColumn = board[0].length ;
            }
            currColumn-- ;
            symbol = 'W' ;
        }
        board[currRow][currColumn] = symbol ;
    }

    public boolean canTakeStep()
    {
        boolean stepOk = true ;

        if (board[currRow + 1][currColumn] == symbol)
        {
            if (step(2) == SOUTH)
            {
                stepOk = false ;
            }
        }

        if (board[currRow - 1][currColumn] == symbol)
        {
            if (step(8) == NORTH)
            {
                stepOk = false ;
            }
        }

        if (board[currRow][currColumn + 1] == symbol)
        {
            if (step(6) == EAST)
            {
                stepOk = false ;
            }
        }

        if (board[currRow][currColumn - 1] == symbol)
        {
            if (step(4) == WEST)
            {
                stepOk = false ;
            }
        }

        return stepOk ;
    }

    public int length() 
    {        
        if (canTakeStep() == true)
        {
            lengthOfWalk++ ;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The length of your walk was: " + lengthOfWalk) ;
        }

        return lengthOfWalk ;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        printTopBottom() ;

        for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
        {
            System.out.print("|") ;

            for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++)
            {
                if (symbol == '$' || symbol == 'N' || symbol == 'S' || symbol == 'W' || symbol == 'E') 
                {
                    if (board[r][c] != symbol)
                    {
                        System.out.print(" ") ;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print(symbol) ;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("|") ;
        }

        printTopBottom() ;
    }

    private void printTopBottom()
    {
        System.out.print("+") ;

        for (int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++)
        {
            System.out.print("-") ;
        }

        System.out.println("+") ;
    }
}
```

And here is the driver class with the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class Lab2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;

        System.out.print("Enter number of rows: ") ;
        int numRows = input.nextInt() ;
        System.out.print("Enter number of columns: ") ;
        int numColumns = input.nextInt() ;
        System.out.print("Enter start row: ") ;
        int startRow = input.nextInt() ;
        System.out.print("Enter start column: ") ;
        int startColumn = input.nextInt() ;

        System.out.println() ;

        SelfAvoidingRandomWalk selfAvoidingRandomWalk = new SelfAvoidingRandomWalk(numRows, numColumns, 
            startRow, startColumn) ;

        selfAvoidingRandomWalk.print() ;

        while (selfAvoidingRandomWalk.canTakeStep() == true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the direction you'd like to go: ") ;
            int theMove = input.nextInt() ;

            selfAvoidingRandomWalk.step(theMove) ;
            selfAvoidingRandomWalk.print() ;
        }

        selfAvoidingRandomWalk.length() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what are you aiming to do. The variable `direction` needs to be declared in the `canTakeStep()` method unless it has already been declared elsewhere as a global variable. In fact, since you are passing that variable as an argument to the `step` method, it should be defined as well, not just declared.

Comment: Also note that in the `canTakeStep` method, you are expecting the `step` method call to return something but the latter doesn't actually return anything. And also, the `step` method expects the argument to be an integer as per the definition but you are handling it as if were a text string.

Comment: @Hiren It won't allow me to define the variable direction anywhere because it is already declared in the step method, and the step method HAS to be void in this case.  Also, I have constants set up for the step method so it seems like I am handling the arguments as a text string but it is really as integers.

Comment: Yes it has been declared in the `step` method as an argument but then you should be simply passing in the actual integers/strings itself  in the call to `step`, instead of using `step(direction)`, e.g. `step(1)` or `step("NORTH")` etc. And even in that case, it won't actually return anything. Then you won't be able to compare it in the `canTakeStep` method.

Comment: @Hiren I see what you mean...Let me explain what I'm trying to do exactly.  I'm working with a 2D char Array.  The class is SelfAvoidingRandomWalk.  We need the user to input the number of rows and columns and then input a start row and start column.  Then we need to record and print every step the mover makes, (NORTH = 8, SOUTH = 2, WEST = 4, EAST = 6), and if they run into an occupied "cell" then we output the length of the walk.  Our professor provides us with sample code to use, and we MUST stick with what he gives us.  The step method in his sample has return type void.

Comment: @Hiren so unless there's another way to write the boolean method canTakeStep without calling on the step method, I'm pretty much screwed here as I can't return anything in the step method.

Comment: Then in that case it would be hard to believe that you have been asked to use anything like `step(direction) == EAST`....the professor would seriously know that `void` methods don't return anything.

Comment: Anyway, now since it is clear that `direction` is being passed from elsewhere, please paste (at least) the relevant code from the entire class, not just these 2 methods.

Comment: @Hiren the if-statements in my boolean canTakeStep() method were my own idea, I thought it might work.  He only tells us what methods we have to have, and the return type.

Comment: @Hiren My code still needs a lot of work...but I'll post what I have so far.  Hopefully you can make sense of it.

Comment: The print() and printTopBottom() methods are solely there to serve as the border for the array, it has nothing to do with the array itself.

Comment: This code too seems to be a little incomplete. There is a user-defined `length()` method but if I am not wrong I do not see any line calling that method. More importantly, since this code does not have even a `main` method, surely there is some more code which is still missing (which is necessary to understand the sequence of control flow)

Comment: @hiren We have a driver class as well.  Probably should've posted that also...will do so right away.

Comment: @Hiren the length() method still needs a lot of work, in fact, it all does really.  I'm just trying to tackle my problems one by one, so am focusing on the boolean method first.

Comment: Yes, now I see that this really does need a lot of work. Now I see in the driver class that you are calling the (problematic) `canTakeStep()` method even before the call to `length()`. I think it will be better to first construct some kind of an architecture using UML and THEN implement it in the code. Don't forget to include the return types and parameters of different methods while constructing the diagram. (And of course, also keep in mind your required constraints). Any further attempt at fixing the code (without having a meaningful architecture) will likely break more than it can fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your step method receives the int direction parameter and your canTakeStep method does not. Just pass the variable the same way you're doing on the step method:

```
public boolean canTakeStep(int direction)
{

}
```

Comment: That would require me to define the variable direction, and that depends on the user's input which is a part of another method.

Comment: yeap, but otherwise you won't be able to use the variable into that method